# Use MailApp to send formatted data from spreadsheet in htmlBody

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send some data automatically from a Google Spreadsheet.
It works OK, but the layout is plain text with no formatting, as in a standard CSV file.

I found the [Sending emails from a Spreadsheet tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) in the Google Developer site, and I want a range from my Google Spreadsheet to be added as HTML
in the mail content. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

I have tried with the function `MailApp.sendEmail ({recipient, subject, htmlBody: body});`, but when defining my "var body" I obviously have the problem.

The range would be something like `A1:E15`, where row A contains the headline.

As a result in the mail I get this:

> [Object Object]

All I need is basically the data in rows and columns as in the spreadsheet
The brilliant solution would be to define a start position like cell A1 and then show/use data until next empty row.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have code that sends data from the spreadsheet, we'll only look at how to generate the HTML body for nicely formatted output.

I've published the [SheetConverter Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter), with a `convertRange2html()` function that can be given a Range object and return the contents as a formatted HTML table. (The library code is available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/6455765).)

If libraries are new to you, read the [Libraries overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) from the Google Developers site.

To get all the data of a spreadsheet sent to yourself as an HTML table:

```js
...
var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var subject = "Spreadsheet contents";
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
var body = "Here is the table:<br/><br/>"
         + htmlTable
         + "<br/><br/>The end."
MailApp.sendEmail({recipient, subject, htmlBody: body});
...
```

Comment: Is that your library, sir? If so, I give you props! Just discovered it a couple days and saved me a big headache.

Comment: @Gerneio - Yes, it's mine, I'm glad it's helped! The trickiest parts of it are no longer required, as Google has provided the ability to get the formatted content of cells now, but it still works fine.

Comment: Hello, is this libary still active?