# Send email from a spreadsheet with whole formatting and borders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi am trying to send a table to a mail from a google spreadsheet but all am getting is "[object Object]" in mail, here is my script.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var range = s.getRange('A1:D8');
  var to = "srinath@example.com";
  var body = '';
  var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
var body = "Here is the table:<br/><br/>"
     + htmlTable
     + "<br/><br/>The end."

  MailApp.sendEmail(to, 'Subject', {htmlBody: body});
};
```

I want t send the whole table and formatting in to tha mail body
I got Sheetconverter Libraries from this link [Use MailApp to send formatted data from spreadsheet in htmlBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577984/use-mailapp-to-send-formatted-data-from-spreadsheet-in-htmlbody/36834398?noredirect=1#comment61241756_36834398)
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending HTML in the body of an email, you need to include options specifically stating that there is an HTML body.

```
MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Subject', body, {htmlBody: body})
```

The `{htmlBody: body}` bit is what you where missing.

Modified code:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var range = s.getRange('A1:D8');
  var to = "srinath@example.com";
  var body = '';
  var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
var body = "Here is the table:<br/><br/>"
     + htmlTable
     + "<br/><br/>The end."

  MailApp.sendEmail(to, 'Subject', body, {htmlBody: body});
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick suggestion, but still its not working, now instead of html code, I get this "[object Object]" in mail. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @munnasri Can you post your code for the sendMail call? This is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I have posted the  whole code in question itself, 'function sendEmail() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var range = s.getRange('A1:D8');
  var to = "srinath@example.com";
  var body = '';
  var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
var body = "Here is the table:<br/><br/>"
     + htmlTable
     + "<br/><br/>The end."

  MailApp.sendEmail(to, 'Subject', body, {htmlBody: body});
};'

Comment: @munnasri In the code in your question, you are missing the `body` parameter in the `sendEmail` method call. Which requires four parameters, only three are supplied which it then assumes the object `{htmlBody: body}` is the text body of the email.