# Send email from a spreadsheet with formatting, borders and automatic line return

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send email automaticaly from a SpreadSheet using SheetConverter library.

I have a problem because the function convertRange2html does not maintain borders nor automatic line return (see screenshots)

Here is the formatted Range in SpreadSheet

[image: Here is the formatted Range in SpreadSheet]

And here is what I get from email
[image: And here is what I get from email]

To illustrate, here is a sample of my code  :

```
var emailOrga = ss.getRange("CG5").getValue();
var emailSubject = ss.getRange("B7").getValue();

var mailRange =  ss.getRange("B10:H50");
var htmlBody = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(mailRange);

var mailBody = "Transfère le à tous les participants <br/><br/>" + htmlBody + "<br/><br/>"

MailApp.sendEmail(emailOrga, emailSubject, mailBody, {htmlBody : mailBody});
```

I would like to know if my format problems come from the code I've written badly, or if anyone has a tool to improve the convertRange2html function?

Comment: requesting off-site resources is considered off topic on stack overflow.

Comment: I don't see any error with your code as compared to these SO posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529890) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837616/send-email-from-a-spreadsheet-with-whole-formatting-and-borders). Make sure that you have added the library properly. Check this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter) on how to install the library that can retrieve the contents of a spreadsheet range in plain text or html, preserving the formatting that is present in the spreadsheet.